# what is the minimum pumping length of the language $\{1011\}$

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

the language $\{1011\}$ can't be pumped because there is no way we can apply the pumping lemma on it and get something in the language. What would be the pumping length?

Answer (score 1):

Pumping length 5.  There aren't any strings of length greater than or equal to 5 in $\{1011\}$, so the condition for the pumping lemma is vacuously true.

Comment: What about the minimum pumping length for the language of the empty string?. Is it 1?

Comment: Yes, it is for the same reason.

Comment: and the language of $\sum^*$ 1 as well right?

Comment: Yes, but for a different reason.

Comment: Considering all the possibilities for $\sum*$. It's either empty or infinite. If it's empty, then it just contains the empty string. If it's infinite then it's alphabet at least contains one character. Both cases result in a minimum pumping length of 1. Is that correct?